# Java: Run or Initiate application on deployment

Tags: java, servlets

I am facing a requirement in which I want application to run after it gets deployed.

I have been able to find only the following method:

In web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.AppContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In the class:

```
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent)
}
```

But this requires to set up a ServletContextListener for each web app.

Are there any other ways to make an application run automatically after deployment?

The solution does not have to be specifically for web applications.

Comment: ServletContextListener gets callbacks on the lifecycle of the servlet context from the web container. If the solution should not be specifically for web applications, then what exactly do you mean with 'during time of deployment'.

Comment: Do you mean while an application is deployed or right after it has deployed?

Comment: I mean right when application got deployed, a method gets call automatically.

Comment: Having the general nature of a container where you deploy to you will always have to take use of external (deployment-) tools/ code to start a application right after successful deployment - because for your application to be able to receive anything (_"I mean right when application got deployed, a method gets call automaticially"_) it must be started. You could google for "automated deployment java" since this oftenly contains the step to start applications after the (automated) deployment - we use CA RA here afaik (i am a bit away from our companies deployment team)